# us keyboard, german layout - special character < and >

Tags: keyboard, layout, english, german

i currently have an american keyboard with the corrsponding us layout (it is the surface type cover btw). As I am used to the german layout i changed the layout settings to german under win8.1. This works fine except for one little thing:

The < and > on the german keyboard are located between the left shift and the z (or y on the german keyboard). However this additional key is missing on the us keyboard. Is this character unavailable when using this setup or did I just not find it yet?

Thanks for your help!

**Solution:**

I used auto hotkey to create a custom keymapping. The code for autohotkey is

```
^!,::
   Send {<}
return

^!.::
   Send {>}
return
```

Comment: However < is `Shift+,` and > is `Shift+.` I think they would come back to US form because as you may know each key has a code and what code `Shift+,` calls is like the one called individually on German Keyboard. So you may not have problem. why r u waiting? check it yourself!

Comment: that is what it would be like when I completly used the american layout. However by changing it to the german layout (on software side) `shift + ,` becomes `;`. Furthermore `y` and `z`are switched (which is they way it should be) and also many other keys have changed positions

Comment: @newBee it would be better if you posted your solution as an actual answer rather than editing it into your question.

Comment: but this way i could award the "right answer" badge to the guy who actually solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several keys on a German layout (QWERTZ) keyboard which don't exist on an American layout (QWERTY) keyboard. In order to regain the ability to use the various disparate features, you would need to utilize software capable of remapping keys. If you're in Windows, AutoHotKey does a fair job of easily allowing custom keystrokes.

Comment: it worked. I edited my answer to show the actual solution with autohotkey.

Comment: Glad you got it working!