# American keyboard with Swedish layout where is "pipe" and "tag" keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

So as the title states I have a physical american keyboard but in Windows I am using a Swedish layout.'
How do I enter the "greater/less, open/closen tag" <> character and the "pipe" | character?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/561747/issue-sony-vaio-greater-than-and-less-than-french-keyboard

Comment: Also related: https://superuser.com/questions/815834/us-keyboard-german-layout-special-character-and?rq=1

Comment: and https://superuser.com/questions/1020203/typing-and-characters-with-ansi-keyboard-lacking-the-key-these-characters-ar?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Just messed around with this. I got a mechanical keyboard with US layout for a good price and my coding ability was struck down when I saw I was missing the <>| key.

I am running Linux (Manjaro & Ubuntu) Here is how I solved it:

I made a variant of the Swedish keyboard layout and made <>| 3rd level (AltGr) from keys ,.- (se-layout... corresponding to ,./ on us-layout)

Seemed like a small enough mod and it coincides fairly well with what is printed on the physical keys on the US keyboard.

Note: For me, `sudo` was not good enough. Had to go `su` instead!

1)------
add the following to the bottom of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/se`

```
// Swedish US_keyMod
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "se_uskeymod" {

    include "se(basic)"

    name[Group1]="Swedish (US key-mod)";

    key <AB08> { [     comma,  semicolon, less,  dead_ogonek ] };
    key <AB09> { [    period,   colon, greater, dead_abovedot ] };
    key <AB10> { [     minus, underscore, bar, dead_abovedot ] };
};
```

2)------
open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` and track down where the segment is for Swedish. Find where the Swedish  starts and add the following variant along with the existing ones...

```
<variant>
  <configItem>
    <name>se_uskeymod</name>
    <description>Swedish (US key-mod)</description>
  </configItem>
</variant>
```

3)------
in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` find the line

```
! variant
```

and look for Swedish layout variants. When you find them squeeze in the folliwing line somewhere there

```
se_uskeymod   se: Swedish (US key-mod)
```

4)------
Verify intended result with `gkbd-keyboard-display -l "se(se_uskeymod)"`

AltGr-mod of , . - should display < > |

5)------ Pick the modded variant of Swedish as your keyboard layout and fire away.

Optionally add [SWERTY layout](http://johanegustafsson.net/projects/swerty/), available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10/11, you can solve this by installing PowerToys ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/)) and remapping the keys using their Keyboard Manager. Note that you will need to use the On-screen Keyboard ([tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-the-on-screen-keyboard-osk-to-type-ecbb5e08-5b4e-d8c8-f794-81dbf896267a)) in order to map to keys which are not available (such as |,<,>).

Step-by-Step:

1. Once you've downloaded PowerToys, navigate to Keyboard Manager.
2. Select "Remap a key", which opens the window in the bottom.
3. Find the physical key you want to re-assign, either through the drop-down or with the Type-window. And then click the "Type" button for the "Mapped To".

Note that you cannot map a key combination, only a single key. For instance you cannot map: **Ctrl+;** or **Alt+K**.

[image: Steps 1-3]

4. To easily map to the key that's missing from your physical keyboard use the Windows On-screen Keyboard. Simply click the key that you want your physical key to map to.

4a. If your key is missing, ensure that you are viewing the full On-screen keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: Don't mind Toto, this is actually a great answer that nobody else had brought up, but more detail on the process would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

All three use a key found to the left of the "z" key and to the right of a half-sized shift key found on ISO 102/105 keyboards. But US Keyboards are missing it.

You can enable the On-Screen Keyboard in windows settings for those times you need to use that key. With the Swedish language enabled the on-screen keyboard will include the missing key.

See below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well aware of how it looks on a swedish keyboard, but I was feeling pretty stupid not finding them with the US layout, but the comments above about related threads seems to answer the question that it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't exist, sorry. It's physically not there. But hopefully toggling the on-screen keyboard can save you in those cases you need to use that key, which I hope is rare. ;)

Comment: haha developer/sysadmin in windows platforms..... so not that rare.......

Comment: I worried that... being you are here. For me, because the on-screen keyboard responds to keypresses on the real keyboard, I can click just the one missing key when I need it but type all others and shift on the physical board.  That's the only option short of buying an international board with the missing key.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the characters does not exist using a swedish layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem trying to use the UK layout setting with a US keyboard on a laptop. In my case I'm struggling to type the `\` and `|` characters. The US keyboard **does** have a key with those symbols on it (next to the `Enter` key) but when using UK layout settings that key actually produces `#` and `~`.

The key I'm trying to find would usually be to the left of the `Z` key, however this US keyboard simply has a much wider `Shift` key and the physical key is just missing. I won't stop to count the keys, but I assume this is the difference between a 101-key (US) layout and a 102-key layout.

**HOWEVER** I'm able to type the characters I want by holding down the `AltGr` key (the right-hand `ALT` key in case that's all the label shows) and then use the physical key with `\` and `|` on it.

In order to get the `|` character I need to hold down the `Shift` key as well.

I hope that there might be a similar trick for the Swedish layout that works for you.